# Syntactic category (awareness) of define-as-computed macro?

Tags: macros, specman

I want to create two macros that use the same match expression but are distinguished by their syntactic category, i.e. action or expression. 
For example I want to express

```
var x := obj.foo(); // value-returning
...
obj.foo(); // not value-returning
```

Using the following macro definitions:

```
define <my_macro_void_call'action> "<obj'exp>.foo" as computed {
   <if in expression context>
     reject_match()
   <else>
     do_something
};

define <my_macro_call'expr> "<obj'exp>.foo" as computed {
   <if in action context>
     reject_match()
   <else>
     do_something
};
```

Is this possible at all? I know that I can use "compute" to call a value-returning method in a void context, but it is not as nice.

Comment: You're trying to use the macro to emulate both a command (does something to change the state) and a query (returns something). This isn't in the spirit of the command/query separation principle.

Comment: I would be happy with "query" on its own, but unlike other languages (e.g. Perl) you cannot call a value-returning method in a void-context, unless you prefix it with "compute".

Comment: Terminology clarification: a query just returns something, without modifying the state. If you don't use that return value, there's no point in calling the query.

Comment: I disagree. Only "pure" methods don't change a state. There is no restriction in e that prevents you from changing state in a value returning method.

Comment: I don't mean that the language doesn't support it, just that in the software world it's discouraged: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to ask in what context the macro was matched, because the interpreter will handle that for you. Here's an example with a function that either returns `TRUE` in expression context or prints out something in action context:

```
define <my_macro_void_call'action> "some_function" as computed {
  print "matched in action context";
  result ="out(\"here I am in action context\");";
};

define <my_macro_call'exp> "some_function" as computed {
  print "matched in expression context";
  result = "TRUE";
};
```

The interpreter will know which one to expand depending on the context where `some_function` is seen in:

```
extend sys {
  run() is also {
    some_function;

    if some_function {
      out("here I was used in expression context");
    }
  };
};
```

You can easily modify these macros to take an object to call a method on.

Comment: This is what I tried as well. My problem was that I tried to test the expression context maco using "print some_function" - but here the interpreter will put it in an action context.

Comment: @Thorsten I'd file it as a bug, because as per the e language reference, print has the following BNF: p[r[int]] exp[,...]

Comment: @Thorsten Tried it in INCISIV/14.20.003 and there I can do `print some_function` and it will show me `some_function = TRUE`

Comment: Right, it works as expected in your example. But if I extend the macros to match `<exp>.some_function` and do a `print some_obj.some_function`, it prints "here I am in action context".

Comment: So the root cause of my problem is the match expression `<exp>.some_function`.
It matches all of e.g. `var x:= some_obj.some_function` - which is correctly considered as an action - and not just the right-hand side of that which I expected. To fix this, I have to come up with a different syntax for the macros.

Comment: Still seems fishy, 'cause `var x:= some_obj` isn't an expression. An assign should be an action.

Comment: Indeed, `var x:= some_obj` isn't an expression and shouldn't have been matched like this. But in practice it's not really that bad, because usually when you have a macro with an `<exp>`, you would append it somewhere to the result string, which would eventually be rejected by the parser. For example, if you had `result = append("out(\"the expression is \",", <exp>, ")")` in the first macro, then `var x:= some_obj` would be eventually rejected (because it's not valid in the context of `out()`) and you would get `TRUE` from the second macro as expected.

Comment: @YuriTsoglin But doesn't the parser first (wrongly) match and then trigger a syntax error after doing the macro expansion?

Comment: Not exactly. When the parser makes an attempt to match a construct using a certain alternative (possibly involving macros), and such an attempt fails, it then "backtracks" and tries to match with other alternatives. In the example I mentioned before, after the parser fails to match the whole action with the `<action>` macro, it would still try to match it as the predefined var declaration action, which would succeed.
Only when all possiblities are tried and all fail, the parser issues a syntax error.